# Using std::for_each on call a function with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I did search, but the closest [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393056/stdfor-each-usage-on-member-function-with-two-args) , among those found,  even doesn't match my problem.
I have a `std::vector<double> mydata` array. I like to use `for_each` for that `mydata` array in calling a member function. That member function accepts two arguments. One is each element of `mydata` array and another one is a `int*` of another array. I do like

```
::std::for_each (mydata.begin(), mydata.end(), train(net));
```

That gives me a compilation error of `train` function does not take one argument. I know how to use for_each if there isn't `int*`.

My train function is

```
void train(double const & data, int* d){}
```

How can I make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Can you not supply a default for int* d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use a lambda-function:

```
std::for_each (mydata.begin(), mydata.end(), [&](double d)
{
  train(d, net);
});
```

Comment: Why take `net` by reference? I'd do `[net](double d){ train(d, net); }` - just copy the pointer.

Answer (score 7):

If you have C++11 you can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
using namespace std::placeholders;  // For `_1`

std::for_each (mydata.begin(), mydata.end(),
               std::bind(&MyClass::train, this, _1, net));
```

Here the member-function will be called with *three* arguments: The first is the `this` pointer, which is always a hidden first argument in all member functions. The second will be the first argument passed to the callable object created by `std::bind`, and the third argument is the `net` variable.

Comment: Why use `std::bind`, when lambda is a lot simpler.  (In pre-C++11, this would be a good use of `boost::bind`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Didn't think of it until I'd already written my answer. And that's why I upvoted the answer from Alexander. :)

Comment: The semantics of `bind` are clearer than that of a lambda function, in my opinion.